# How to use window .fetch to load local json data (ES6)

Tags: javascript, json, promise, webpack, fetch-api

I have a JSON object (agendaItemsJson) that I load using ES6 syntax (using json-loader via webpack). Using the following gives an error because fetch is trying to parse an URL and agendaItemsJson is an object.

So my question is how can I mimic this correctly so that I am able to use a promise and get agendaItemsJson to be my response.

```
'use strict';

import BaseService from './base-service';
import agendaItemsJson from '../json/agenda.json';

class _AgendaService extends BaseService {

    getAgenda() {
        // TODO: Will use API instead of the JSON here under.
        return this.fetch(agendaItemsJson)
            .then(response => response);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just return a promise that is resolved with your agendaItemsJson? I.E use ES6 promises? You could even defer the response with setTimeout to simulate network delays.

```
getAgenda(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(agendaItemsJson);
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an exemple please?

Comment: I've edited my post to give you an idea what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

If agendaItemsJson is the object you want to use as response using a promise you could do just this:

```
return Promise.resolve(agendaItemsJson);
```

This is shorter than creating a new Promise and it will resolve the value immediately.

And BTW, you wouldn't have to wait for a timeout to be executed.

Comment: The idea of the timeout was purely to simulate network delay (perhaps for demonstrating UI loading / blocking) hence the constructed promise.